# Angular 5 in Visual Studio 2017 not seeing file changes

Tags: angular, typescript, webpack, visual-studio-2017

I upgraded a Visual Studio 2017 Angular 4 template project to Angular 5 using the instructions at:

http://www.talkingdotnet.com/upgrade-angular-4-app-angular-5-visual-studio-2017/

However, when I update an HTML or Typescript file and run, the changes are not reflected in the browser, either in the HTML itself or in the TS files in "sources" when viewed in the Chrome debugger.

I did not have this issue with the Angular 4 template before doing the upgrade.

Any ideas? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue when I upgrade from angular 5 to angular 7, delete the "dist" folder in the ClientApp folder and it should work.